# How to read an rtf from a file and insert it into a body of an Outlook item?

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

I am attempting to write an Outlook Add-In that has functionality very similar to the insert signature feature of Microsoft Outlook.  I best and most detailed thread I found discussing something similiar to this is [found here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/02056c49-f3ac-4e46-bedf-2c6f849d7bce)

The problem with my code is the memorystream, despite being an rtf file able to be opened from word, returns a null.

```
doc = ms as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document ;
```

I'm attempting to get this to work

```
    if (selObject is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem obj = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)selObject;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = obj.GetInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            String path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                "Outlook", "Intercall.rtf");

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                Stream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open);
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                doc = ms as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document ;
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect expect that the cast from MemoryStream to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document to succeed? MemoryStream knows nothing nabout Word or any other COM object. You need to expliiclty create an instance of the Word.Application object use it to load the RTF. You can also use Inspector.WordEditor in the Outlook Object Model to get the instance of the Word.Document object.